# How to change logical volume UUID?

Tags: lvm

I have two disks, one is 1TB and the second is 2TB big. I created partitions on a 2TB disk and copied partitions by `dd` command. Everything works fine when only a 2TB disk is used. Partitions are enlarged, LVM LV and file systems are also. But of course LVM VG/PV/LV UUIDs are same on both disks. I already changed VG UUID, VG name, file system UUID, and PV UUID on 1TB which is doing as a temporary backup. But I don't know how to change LV UUID. When I try to mount LV volume from 1TB disk it mounts a partition from 2TB.

[image]

How to change LV UUID?

Comment: this relates to UUID of VG, not LV

Answer (score 3):

There is `pvchange --uuid`. There is `vgchange --uuid`.

So one would expect `lvchange --uuid`, but it does not exist.

Why not? See [Bug 979720 - provide a --uuid command for lvchange](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=979720).

To summarize, the LV UUID is meant for internal use only. The user is not meant to have any control over it.

If you don't agree with this argument, you can still change it — by making a new LV and copying data over, or by editing metadata directly e.g. by using `vgcfg{backup,restore}`, or by deleting the LV altogether and re-creating it.

Re-creating only works *using the exact same list of extents* to be specified as `PV:PE±PE` arguments (see lvcreate manpage), and you also must disable `issue_discards` and use `--wipesignatures n`. Otherwise your data is gone.

Since this is very dangerous — if in doubt, just leave as is.

---

LVM2 itself does not care about the identical LV UUID's. You can change PV/VG UUIDs with `vgimportclone` or `pvchange`, `vgchange` and it seems you already did that.

In regards to mounting, what you really need to change is the filesystem UUID, you can do that with `tune2fs -U` (for ext4) or the relevant tool for your filesystem. It's not related to LVM2.

In the future instead of using `dd`, you can also consider using LVM's own tools for moving data around such as `pvmove`.